# insert a PDF with FPDF

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

It is possible to insert an image in a pdf document with FPDF using this command :

```
fpdf.image(name, x = None, y = None, w = 0, h = 0, type = '', link = '')
```

My question is: is it possible to do the same but instead of inserting an image I want to insert another PDF ( corresponding to a graphic) as an image ( or as a new page if it is the only possibility)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer the best I can; please let me know if it is not clear.

In order to add a PDF inside another PDF, you can use the `template` method.

From the [docs](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/index.html):

1. Create an instance of FPDF

```py
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
```

2. Insert the PDF file at the right position and size

```py
pdf.template('the_pdf_to_insert.pdf', x = 10, y = 10, w = 80, h = 30, type = 'P')
```

*Make sure that the orientation is set the right way. Use either `P` for portrait or `L` for landscape.*

3. And the last step, save the file

```py
pdf.output('document_with_image.pdf')
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: @WinterGrim did you mean, to use another PDF as a page in the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, one can convert the PDF file that you want to insert into an image format that FPDF supports.

```
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 14)
```

###### Insert the PDF file at the correct position

```
pdf.template('pdf_to_insert.pdf', x = 50, y = 50, w = 60, h = 40, type = 'P')
```

```
pdf.output('output_image.pdf')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the PDF file that you want to insert into an image format that FPDF supports (such as with the pillow library).

Once you have converted the PDF file to an image format, you can use the fpdf.image method as you did above to insert it into your PDF document. For example, to insert the image at the top-left corner of the page, you could do the following:

```
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image("my_image.jpg", x = 0, y = 0)
pdf.output("output.pdf")
```